# Location of front code in backend repository

Tags: angularjs, node.js, spring-boot

Not sure if this is the right forum to ask such questions.

We have a project which is using spring+gradle for backend and angular for frontend. These two are separate repositories at the moment. We are trying to merge these two different repositories in single repo for ease of development.

The question I have with this merge is whether we should merge these two projects as two separate independent projects or we should embed Angular code as a subdirectory inside backend project?

In my opinion we should have two different disconnected directories, as this code is no way dependent on each other. but in that case we will have to maintain two different build script etc. Also in some of spring+angular tutorials I saw angular code embedded as a "resource" in spring project, so wondering what is the industry practice in such scenarios

Please help.

Comment: How do you deploy the code? If backend and frontend is deployed separately, store them in separate modules. If the frontend code ends up anyway in the resulting war file, then you can also add it to the first module. There is no right answer in the end, it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: In our case frontend is deployed in s3 bucket. and in all cases frontend and backend are two different applications.

Comment: Well, then it's clear. If you want to have them in one repository, at least keep them in different modules.